# SearchTerms javaxmail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to search emails between today and before 15days.

```
ReceivedDateTerm fromDate=new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LE, new Date(2017, 02, 16));
ReceivedDateTerm toDate=new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GE, new Date(2017, 02, 01));
SearchTerm term=new AndTerm(toDate, fromDate);
Message messages[] = folder.search(term);
System.out.println("Total Messages : "+messages.length);
it is showing 0 result;
```

But it is not working;
So how to do it?

Comment: Try to change the SearchTerm like the way mentioned in following article...
http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/using-javamail-for-searching-e-mail-messages

Comment: It works but it is too slow searching. it is finding one by one email from first email.
So is any other way to fast searching?

Comment: The code above should work.  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?  What version of JavaMail are you using?  When using IMAP, JavaMail knows how to translate the standard search terms into IMAP commands.  The link referenced above won't do that, and thus will be much slower.